# a reference to const works but plain reference fails

Tags: c++, reference, expression, constants, variable-assignment

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class point
{
public:
    int x,y;

    inline int getX() { return x; } 
    inline int getY() { return y; }
    inline void setX(int v) { x=v; }
    inline void setY(int v) { y=v; }
};

point operator+ (point& p1, point& p2) 
{
    point sum = {p1.x+p2.x, p1.y+p2.y};
    return sum;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, point& p)
{
    out<<"("<<p.x<<","<<p.y<<")";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    point a={3,5},b={6,7};
    cout<<"Sum="<<a+b;
}
```

The above code fails with compilation error:

> startingClasses.C:33:17: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘point&’ from an rvalue of type ‘point’
>     cout<<"Sum="<

But this below code works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class point
{
public:
    int x,y;

    inline int getX() { return x; } 
    inline int getY() { return y; }
    inline void setX(int v) { x=v; }
    inline void setY(int v) { y=v; }
};

point operator+ (point& p1, point& p2) 
{
    point sum = {p1.x+p2.x, p1.y+p2.y};
    return sum;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, **const** point& p)
{
    out<<"("<<p.x<<","<<p.y<<")";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    point a={3,5},b={6,7};
    cout<<"Sum="<<a+b;
}
```

Adding `const` in the code makes it work... Still don't understand.

Comment: What do you think &p=d+e means?

Comment: oh... since d+e is a constant, we need to add const., but a reference by default is a const, so why do you have to explicitly add a const keyword?

Comment: I'll rephrase - what do you think &p means?

Comment: in any case, please don't write code like this, it's prone to errors and confusing (as you figured) https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-name-one

Comment: I'll follow up on UKMonkey's question. What do you get when you write `d+e`? Even on a standalone statement.

Comment: @juanchopanza: He's asking the OP to think about it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I had assumed OP already knew that. I was having a period of over-optimism.

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's pretty dangerous in these parts :P

Comment: Sorry guys, could you please give me a direct answer, I still dont understand where this is leading.

Comment: "but a reference by default is a const" Where did you learn that? No! It is completely false!! `int& r = ...` and `const int& r = ...` are very much different. One defines a reference to int, the other defines a constant reference to int.

Comment: @PradeepAnbumani It is in the duplicate. A non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object. In your code, `a+b` is one of these temporary objects (simplifying the terminology.)

Comment: d+e may be a temporary or it may be a constexpr if the compiler optimises it.

Comment: Thanks @juanchopanza!

Comment: @bolov, that's not quite right. The other defines a *reference to a const int*. The placement of *const* in the sentence matters as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller I am quite right.

Comment: @bolov, [no you are not](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#overview-const). The FAQ uses the term *reference-to-const* and not *const-reference* for a reason.

Comment: @StoryTeller see for instance C++14 draft §14.1.6 "const int& cri = i; // OK: const reference bound to ..."

Comment: @StoryTeller In the C++ standard "const reference" appears 14 times.  "reference to const" appears 2 times, one of which is to point that it is wrong to call declared entity in the example "reference to const"

Comment: @StoryTeller and no, the placement of `&` does not matter in this case. And "reference to const" and "const reference" informally both denote the same thing.

Comment: @bolov, when did I ever say the placement of & matters? Don't straw-man me, please.

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry, missed the "in the sentence". My bad.